# Trying to populate form with information from a cookie

Tags: javascript

I am trying to populate a form with details that I have saved in a cookie.

Each cookie has 12 bits of info seperated by '---'

I am trying to make sure username (a value inputted by a user) matches the username (username1) of ONE of the cookies.

How can I do this?

The if loop at the bottom is always populating with the last index in the cookie array

```
function populateForm(username){

         var allcookies = document.cookie;

            // Get all the cookies pairs in an array
            cookiearray  = allcookies.split(';');

            // Now take key value pair out of this array
            for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++){
                username1 = cookiearray[i].split('---')[0];
                password = cookiearray[i].split('---')[1];
                email = cookiearray[i].split('---')[2];
                name_one = cookiearray[i].split('---')[3];
                name_two = cookiearray[i].split('---')[4];
                addr1 = cookiearray[i].split('---')[5];
                addr2 = cookiearray[i].split('---')[6];
                city = cookiearray[i].split('---')[7];
                zip = cookiearray[i].split('---')[8];
                day = cookiearray[i].split('---')[9];
                month = cookiearray[i].split('---')[10];
                year = cookiearray[i].split('---')[11];


                var nameinarray = cookiearray[i].split('---')[0];
                var cityinarray = cookiearray[i].split('---')[7];


                if(nameinarray.indexOf(username.value)){

                        document.getElementById('username_text').value=nameinarray;
                        document.getElementById('city_text').value=cityinarray;
                        alert("in loop " + username.value);

                }

                }


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function returns `-1` if the argument is not found in the *this* string. In many programming languages, including JavaScript, `-1` is treated as a truthy value, and thus, if used in an if-test, will result in the branch being executed.

Solution:

```
if (nameinarray.indexOf(username.value) !== -1) {
```

Other comments on your code:

- I question your use of `indexOf()` here. Shouldn't you want exact equality, i.e. `if (username1 === username.value) {`? But there may be an explanation for your use of `indexOf()` that that I'm not aware of; feel free to add it in the comments.
- You shouldn't repeatedly execute `cookiearray[i].split('---')`; that's wasteful of CPU. Compute it once, assign it to a variable, and then repeatedly index that variable in your 12 assignment statements.
- Not sure why you created both `username1` and `nameinarray`. Ditto for `city` and `cityinarray`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to do username1 == username.value and it would not work (I must have mistyped as is now working)